# How to display an image in a label after retrieveing it from JavaDB database?

Tags: java, database, image, javadb

The below code is supposed to retrieve an image from the database and display it within a jlabel. After lots of trying i cannot get the image to show.  In the code below I first conenct to the JavaDB which is a simple table with only one record containing an image. I then retrieve that record and store it within the existingCustomer object. I then decode the byte array and set the array to an ImageIcon and then set the icon to a label. The problem i am having is that the output is confirming that the byte array has been stored in the icon but it will not show in the label. please help

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    try {
        Customer existingCustomer = new Customer();
        String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/CustDB";
        String uname = "mydb";
        String upass = "mydb";


            //Get a connection
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, uname, upass); 
            System.out.println("Connection OK"); 
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(
            "select photo from APP.CUSTOMER where CUSTOMER_ID = 2");

            while(results.next())
            {
                existingCustomer.setPhoto(results.getBytes(1));                    
            }
            results.close();
            stmt.close();

            byte[] imageData = Base64.base64Decode(existingCustomer.getPhoto());

        System.out.println(imageData);


        if(imageData !=  null)
         {System.out.println("yes");}else{System.out.println("no");}
           ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(imageData);
           //BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData));
        if(icon != null){System.out.println("yes");}else{System.out.println("no");}

           jLabelImage.setText(null);
           jLabelImage.setIcon(icon);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(custform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(custform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(custform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(custform.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of image .jpg?

Comment: What happens if you set the text in your method? If the text displays then you have problems with reading the image. If the text doesn't display then you either 1) haven't added the label to the GUI or 2) you don't have a proper reference to the label.

Comment: Yes its a jpeg file, text can be displayed fine, and i have already tested the image by loading it straight from a file and it displayed fine.

Comment: i replied to the other comment after the first comma, neither suggested solution are the issue

Comment: What happens if you set the text in your method? If the text displays then you have problems with reading the image. If the text doesn't display then you either 1) haven't added the label to the GUI or 2) you don't have a proper reference to the label. – camickr 3 hours ago

Comment: the 1) and 2) are the suggestions i was mentioning i replied to your comment in the first comment i wrote, you clearly read it wrong. I have done those things correctly, please stop this aggression and just help

Comment: That was the first thing i tried and it was not the problem i have tried several different things none have worked so i thought i'd use this site, and i said text can be displayed fine in the first comment i wrote. It is a simple problem, i wish to receive an image stored as an array of bytes and display it in a label, how much more information do you need

Comment: i wish to access the image from a database not a file

Comment: My bad, I'm blind :(. I read the comments 4 times and I missed your response to my question. `i wish to access the image from a database not a file` - sorry I've never done this so I can't help. Hopefully I can offer real help with your next question :)

Comment: haha no worries hopefully someone else can help